# setting cost parameter in vl_feat vl_svmtrain function

Tags: image, matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm

i am interested in using vl_feat library for my image classification project. I want to train a  SVM classifier using  vl_svmtrain function. Can any tell me how can i set cost parameter in vl_svmtrain?

I previously used lib-svm for that purpose over their i just had to specify

> '-c'

parameter.

Answer (score 2):

LibSVM and VLFeat have a different notation regarding the optimization problem inside the SVM training. In LibSVM you have `-c`, that is the regularization term for the problem of the form

[image]

As instead in VLFeat the optimization problem has the form

[image]

and in this case `LAMBDA`, that is the third input argument for `vl_svmtrain()` will be your regularization term.

Screenshot for LibSVM has been taken from [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) whereas screenshot for `vl_smtrain()` has been taken from [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_svmtrain.html)...just in case you want to dive more into details.